# Is there a cleaner way to set this anonymous class property?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I am returning an anonymous class:

```
var clients = from c in this.ClientRepository.SearchClientByTerm(term, 10)
    select new
    {
       id = c.Id,
       line1 = c.Address.Line1 ?? "Unknown Information ..."
    };
```

The problem is Address is nullable which means if it is null it explodes into a million pieces.

The most elegant solution i could think of was this...

```
    line1 = c.Address != null && c.Address.Line1 != null 
               ? c.Address.Line1 : "Unknown Information ..."
```

Is there a better way?, i don't like losing the ability to use the null-coalescing operator and then having to check if null.

Comment: I am using poco's so I set the address there if null. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only cleaner way I can think of is to modify the getter of the `Address` property to never return null, or have the constructor always initialize the `Address`. Otherwise you always need to check for null.

Answer (score 1):

I could only think of this:

```
line1 = c.Address.HasValue ?  c.Address.Line1.HasValue ? c.Address.Line1 : "Line1 unknown." : "Address unknown."
```

You could also modify your Address property get{} method to check for contents and return appropriate value, preferably cache the results so it doesn't run the same check over and over.

Comment: @SaeedAlg: I can't see how this is any uglier than OPs code (not that I think any of it is ugly). I replaced !=null with HasValue, otherwise its pretty much the same. And yes, it is valid too. I also suggested alternative solution. What have you done towards solving the issue? Oh yeah, you've bitched about it. That really made a difference.

Comment: @danijels, @Skurmedel, @Kohan, Too many things are valid but they are not good practice, I'd downvoted danijels to OP do not do same (as doing right now) for the further  what @Darin Dimitrov, says is a better and more clear way, you gonna to do `spaghetti codding` by continue your way, danijels you write a better way in the end of your phrase which is true thing, but my downvote is for tell first paragragh is a wrong way. Also danijels you got 20+ and 2- it's a good trade:D

Comment: @SaeedAlg: I don't really care about the points I get or don't, but I do think your downvoting is both unjustified and off target. If you think the code is ugly, then it is OP you should be downvoting, not me. But there is really no reason for downvoting for something so off-topic IMO. There are plenty of posts to discuss spaghetti code, best practices and such. This is just not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would have `ClientRepository.SearchClientByTerm()` return an initialized `Address` and (possibly) set `Line1` there.